# Выполнение команд извне

Tags: администрирование, docker, docker-compose

Например: я собрал образ node.js

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.9
RUN groupadd user && usermod -a -G user root
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD ["node"]
```

И запускаю контейнер через docker-compose с такой конфигурацией:

```
version: '2'
services:
    node:
        build: ./images/node-6.9
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
```

В `/var/www/app` у меня лежит проект, для которого скажем я хочу запустить тесты. Без докера, я бы это сделал так:

```
cd /var/www/app
node testign.js
```

Но как такое можно сделать внутри контейнера?
Каждый раз набирать `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash`, и уже внутри него `node testign.js` ?

Я читал что выполнять команды внутри контейнера - это плохая практика, если это так, то как тогда как правильно выполнять команды из вне?

Answer (score 0):

Кажется то что нужно:

```
docker run --rm <container> node testign.js
```

Будет запущен новый контейнер, в нем будет запущена команда. --rm нужен для автоматического удаления контейнера после завершения. Также можно добавить -it если нужно интерактивное взаимодействие.